# List the User mapped to a Login on one particular database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, authentication

I'm back here with a SQL User/Login problem.
First off all i'm working on SQL server 2008 and i'm not the master on that server.
On that SQL server i have different Login and these Login are mapped to a USER to my database 'DB_MyDataBase'.
Indeed, i have 10 different Login mapped to 10 different User on my database 'DB_MyDataBase'.

For i.e., when i'm connecting to the SQL server with a Login 'Laurent', That SQL Login 'Laurent' is the USER 'Laurel' on my database 'DB_MyDataBase'. For the moment, no problem.
But now for that 10 different Login and want to know their respective USER for my database 'DB_MyDataBase'.

After some research i've found a request that can do "the job"

```
sp_msloginmappings 'Laurent', 1
```

Normally, that show mapping user account info in current databases context for login account 'Laurent'
But when i tried it, i had a error message.

```
Nom d'objet 'dbo.syslogins' non valide.
```

Error message is : `Object name 'dbo.syslogins' is not valid` for non French users.

I've found another request which is working "a bit".

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      SERVER_name SYSNAME NULL ,
      Database_name SYSNAME NULL ,
      UserName SYSNAME ,
      GroupName SYSNAME ,
      LoginName SYSNAME NULL ,
      DefDBName SYSNAME NULL ,
      DefSchemaName SYSNAME NULL ,
      UserID INT ,
      [SID] VARBINARY(85)
    )

DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX)
--this will contain all the databases (and their sizes!)
--on a server
DECLARE @databases TABLE
    (
      Database_name VARCHAR(128) ,
      Database_size INT ,
      remarks VARCHAR(255)
    )
INSERT  INTO @databases--stock the table with the list of databases
        EXEC sp_databases

SELECT  @command = COALESCE(@command, '') + '
USE ' + database_name + '
insert into #temp (UserName,GroupName, LoginName,
                    DefDBName, DefSchemaName,UserID,[SID])
     Execute sp_helpuser
UPDATE #TEMP SET database_name=DB_NAME(),
                 server_name=@@ServerName
where database_name is null
'
FROM    @databases
EXECUTE ( @command )

SELECT  loginname ,
        UserName ,
        Database_name
FROM    #temp
WHERE   LoginName = 'Laurent'
```

So that one is working it's listing all User mapped to that Login on every database BUT (there is always a "but"...) it's only working with the Login i use to connect.

For i.e. When i connect to the SQL server with Login 'Laurent' the previous request is working because i request for the same Login that i used to connect to the SQL server but when i connect with Login 'Laurent' and do the previous request with a different Login (so not 'Laurent' but another one which have a user mapped to my database 'DB_MyDataBase'.) I don't see anything, it returns me blank column....
Maybe it's because i'm not master on that SQL server.

So how i can list User mapped to a Login different from the one i'm connected?

I hope my question is clear enough (sorry for long text) and thanks for your future answer. Don't hesitate to ask me if you need further info to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

What you can see will depend on the permissions of the user you are logged in as. This query against two of the [security catalog views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178542.aspx) should give you what you want provided you have the necessary permission.

```
select
    dp.name as UserName,
    sp.name as LoginName
from
    sys.database_principals dp
        left join sys.server_principals sp on sp.sid = dp.sid
where
    dp.type in ('S', 'U')
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really close of what i looking for. It gives me all Username for my database 'DB_MyDataBase' but it gives me only the Loginname of the login i use to connect on the SQL server, other are 'null'. Like you said, i think with the premission i have, i can't do better.. :/